# Python: Assigning timestamps to dataframe using separate date and time values in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I load a csv using `df=pd.to_csv(file, header = 0)` and I have two columns, `Date` and `Time`, in these format:
`20120718` (yyyymmdd) and `15:59:56.319000` (H:M:S:MS).

How can I combine both in order to set my dataframe `df` index using this date and timestamps columns and have a proper indexed time-series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.sort_index(by=['Date', 'Time'], inplace=True)
df.index = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
```

Is the easiest way.  If you really want a time series as an index, then:

```
df['timeseries'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time, unit='ms')
```

Comment: thanks but df.Date is in `int`. So I use your code above: `df['timeseries'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date + ' ' + df.Time, unit='ms')` and add `str` to df.Date it screws up everything.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work as an int.  I had thought it was a string.  Try `(df.Date.astype(str) + ' ' + df.Time, unit='ms')`